# Merging outer div with inner div and inner div border active

Tags: html, css, tabs, stylesheet

i creating a tab view using divs. when one of the tab is active, i want to hide the outer divs bottom border so that i see the tab is selected.

but right now i see outer div bottom border, which is not great as in the image.[image]

desired output:

[image]

my div is laid as:

```
<div class='clsTabContainer'>
    <div class='clsCurrentTab'>Dashboard</div>
    <div class='clsTab'>Leads</div>
    <div class='clsTab'>Internet</div>
    <div class='clsTab'>Tasks</div>
</div>

.clsTabContainer {
    BACKGROUND-COLOR: #FFFFFF;
    PADDING-LEFT: 0px;
    WIDTH: 100%;
    PADDING-RIGHT: 0px;
    WHITE-SPACE: nowrap;
    HEIGHT: 35px;
    OVERFLOW: hidden;
    PADDING-TOP: 3px;  
    border-bottom: #D0D0D0 1px solid;
}

.clsTab {
    OVERFLOW-X: visible;
    OVERFLOW-Y: hidden;
    BACKGROUND-COLOR: #F0F0F0;
    DISPLAY: inline-block;
    WHITE-SPACE: nowrap;
    HEIGHT: 100%;
    FONT-SIZE: 10pt;
    VERTICAL-ALIGN: middle;
    CURSOR: pointer;    
    padding: 5px 10px 10px 10px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    border-left: #D0D0D0 1px solid;
    border-right: #D0D0D0 1px solid;
    border-top: #D0D0D0 1px solid;
}

.clsCurrentTab {
    OVERFLOW-X: visible;
    OVERFLOW-Y: hidden;
    BACKGROUND-COLOR: #FFFFFF;
    DISPLAY: inline-block;
    WHITE-SPACE: nowrap;
    HEIGHT: 100%;
    FONT-SIZE: 10pt;
    VERTICAL-ALIGN: middle;
    CURSOR: pointer;    
    padding: 5px 10px 10px 10px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    border-left: #D0D0D0 1px solid;
    border-right: #D0D0D0 1px solid;
    border-top: #82C600 1px solid;
    color: #82C600;
}
```

how to avoid outer divs border bottom on the selected div so that i see the corresponding tab is really looks selected.?

Comment: what exactly do you want to do? can you show image of the desired output?

Comment: PFA image for desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Following are the changes in current css to achieve this:

```
.clsTab {
    height:19px;
}
.clsCurrentTab {
    height:20px;
}
.clsTab,.clsCurrentTab {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Remove `overflow:hidden` from `.clsTabContainer`.

[**See DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/hpbek6rs/1)

Comment: in that case, calculate 100% - top and bottom padding

Comment: its not working for me, can you please tell me how to calculate that padding?

Comment: you can write this : `height:calc(100% - 15px)`, but calc is not a cross-browser function.

Comment: when i try to increase height of selected div (.clsCurrentTab) more than outerdiv (.clstabcontainer), inner div pushes outer div further below rather than hiding outer div.

Comment: @AlagesanPalani can you make a fiddle?

Comment: @Hiral, when i create a fiddle, overflow works and inner div correctly hides the outer div bottom border, but not in my app. is it again anything to do with IE compatibility and quirks mode issue?